# Iterating through describe_instances() to print key & value boto3

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary, boto3

I am currently working on a python script to print pieces of information on running EC2 instances on AWS using Boto3. I am trying to print the InstanceID, InstanceType, and PublicIp. I looked through Boto3's documentation and example scripts so this is what I am using:

```
import boto3    

ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = ec2client.describe_instances()

for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        instance_id = instance["InstanceId"]
        instance_type = instance["InstanceType"]
        instance_ip = instance["NetworkInterfaces"][0]["Association"]

print(instance)
print(instance_id)
print(instance_type)
print(instance_ip)
```

When I run this, "instance" prints one large block of json code, my instanceID, and type. But I am getting an error since adding NetworkInterfaces.

```
instance_ip = instance["NetworkInterfaces"][0]["Association"]
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/me/AWS/describeInstances.py", line 12, in <module>
instance_ip = instance["NetworkInterfaces"][0]["Association"]
KeyError: 'Association'
```

What am I doing wrong while trying to print the PublicIp?

Here is the structure of NetworkInterfaces for reference:
[image: describe_instances()]

The full Response Syntax for reference can be found here (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

Comment: Your error says it's on the line `print(ip['Association']['PublicIp'])`, but you did not include that line in your example.

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: @jordanm, just corrected my post and reran my script to get the above.

Comment: @Marcin, oh....I didn't know that. I'll get that corrected tonight. Thanks for the help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Association` man not always may be present. Also an instance may have more then one interface. So your working loop could be:

```
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        instance_id = instance["InstanceId"]
        instance_type = instance["InstanceType"]
        #print(instance)
        print(instance_id, instance_type)
        for network_interface in instance["NetworkInterfaces"]:
            instance_ip = network_interface.get("Association", "no-association")
            print(' -', instance_ip)
```

Comment: Thanks! So this definitely ran fine and localized the list for Association - {'IpOwnerId': '422180543540', 'PublicDnsName': 'ec2-12-8-09-110.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com', 'PublicIp': '51.9.10.117'} Would I do another for loop to print just the PublicIp by itself?